# usb sound card not loading arch linux

Tags: usb, audio, arch-linux, alsa

I have the following /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf:

```
alias char-major-116 snd
alias snd-card-2 snd-usb-audio
alias snd-card-1 snd-hda-intel
alias snd-card-0 snd hda-intel

options snd cards_limit=3

options snd-usb-audio index=-1
options snd-hda-intel id=PCH index=-2
options snd-hda-intel id=HDMI index=-2
```

I am trying to have my usb audio card load as the default card but the built in card is always loading first. I have the usb card plugged into a hub it that's a problem.

I am running arch Linux
with a i7-4720HQ processor
and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It has nothing to do with the alsa-base.conf.

systemd-modules-load.service was failing because I had a module that didn't exist. When I fixed that the problem went away.